# How To Convert HTTPS POST to HTTP POST

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, https, reverse-proxy

I have an existing web application hosted in Tomcat which is listening for a HTTP POST.

However for security reasons requests to the web application have to be transported across the network as HTTPS.

I cannot change the web application.

So I want to receive a HTTPS POST, decrypt it and pass it on to the web application as a HTTP POST.

I also need to pass back to the sender response codes etc.

I have been told that I can do this using Apache configured as a "reverse proxy".

But I am not an expert at Apache or Tomcat and before I investigate this option I wanted to be sure I was going down the right path.

i.e.

[Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG4u6.png)

So to the Remote Server application everything looks like it happens over HTTPS.

And to my local Tomcat web application everything looks like it happens over HTTP.

Is this doable and correct ?

Do I need to use Apache or could I do it all in Tomcat ?

Is this what is called "url rewriting" ?

This is more than just "redirection" ?

Thanks,
Brett

Comment: You don't have to change the web application. You only have to reconfigure Tomcat so as to have an HTTPS Connector. You don't need Apache HTTPD, although there are plenty of other good reasons for using it in front of your Tomcat.

Comment: @OlafKock I cannot imagine why you removed the [tag:apache] tag when Apache HTTPD is specifically mentioned in the question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Too many open tabs and a short distraction coming in. Thanks @user207421 that you caught it.